# Apache Request Hangs For 2 Minutes Exactly

Tags: networking, dns, apache-httpd

I am experiencing some odd behavior with apache. I have requests that are hanging for exactly two minutes. The request could be one file one time, and then a completely different file another time.

Here are a couple of screenshots of my network inspector.

[image: ss #1]
*original URL: http://tiny-img.com/image.php?di=QNKO*

[image: ss #2]
*original URL: http://tiny-img.com/image.php?di=3BFS*

[image: ss #3]
*original URL: http://tiny-img.com/image.php?di=49VN*

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, there are no errors in the logs, and I'm not finding anything referring to similar issues on the web.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this, and/or if you know what is going on, I would appreciate any insight to what I can do to correct this.

Comment: Depending on how busy the webserver is you could restart httpd via a `strace` that follows spawned children (via `-f`) that would give you more of an indication of what it's trying to do when it hangs (including whether it's waiting on a locked resource to become available, or waiting on a network response). It's probably some sort of a high latency network resource or some sort of QoS control.

Comment: Also, it looks like these are screencaps from Chrome's developer tools feature. You may try to enable `nscd` locally and see if that avoids this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delays like this are often caused by reverse DNS lookups (i.e. resolving an IP address to a hostname).

Do you have HostNameLookups turned on in the apache config?  If so, turn it off.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/100225/apache-httpd-wont-stop-doing-reverse-dns-requests-for-clients-ips for other tips on disabling hostname resolution in apache.

Comment: Agreed. 2 minutes *screams* DNS issues.

Comment: fwiw, it probably is DNS but it could be DNS on the client side as well, especially if the OP is on a weak WiFi connection or something like that. `nscd` is probably a good choice as well (even if only as a troubleshooting tool). Just thought I'd add that to the mix.

Comment: true enough, but if it is client-side, there's not much you can do on the server to solve that.

Comment: No but it does let the OP know that he doesn't have anything to worry about and it's just that his test that's flawed.

Comment: I have HostNameLookups turned off, so its not that, any other ideas?